# Mock test method with the return value

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

How to write a mock test for method with return value(a class instance)

**userService**

```
public User getUserInfo(String userId) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = http:127.0.0.1 + userId ;
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, User.class);
}

public class TimUser {
    private String id = null;
    private String userName = null;
    **********GET & SET method***********;
}
```

---

```
 @Mock
private userService userService;
private String userId;


@Before
public void set_up(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    userId = "";
}

@Test
public void getUserInfo(){

    userService.getUserInfo(userId)

}
```

I don't know how to write a test case for this kind of method, can anyone provide some ideas?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand well the question but from what I can see It seems like you are trying to test your mock ?  In fact I don't see why you would need a mock at all as the result of the getUserInfo() method seems to depend only on the input.

Comment: You don't mock the class you are testing. I think you need to use `@InjectMocks` on your user service and mock restTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

```
Mockito.when(userService.getUserInfo(userId)).thenReturn(value);
```

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here though. If the class you are testing is UserService then you should not be mocking it. You should be calling getUserInfo in your test and asserting the return value is the same as your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use when(mock.method).thenReturn(value) from mockito.

```
when(userservice.getUserInfo(eq(this.userId)).thenReturn(<your value here>)
```